# Can you use python-socketio for django?

Tags: python, django, socket.io

I've looked around for socketio solutions for Django, and I haven't found anything that says I can use python-socketio for it, but I also haven't found anything that says I can't. It's python, so I would assume it works, but is it bad practice? Will something go wrong?

Thank you

Comment: You might want to take a look at [django-channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), which integrates websockets into Django. It is of course possible to use various Django features in python-socketio, but there is no real integration between the two. You'll likely have to run a separate socketio server next to a WSGI server.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there are an example app with django in their repos
https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/python-socketio/tree/master/examples/server/wsgi/django_example